# Self-Made Environment in a LaTeX document

Tags: packages

Is it possible to include a self-made environment in a LaTeX document without using the \usepackage command.

New Environment set of code:

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment {mytabular} { O{\,} }
  {
    \char_set_catcode_other:N \&
    \char_set_catcode_alignment:n {`#1}
    \begin{tabular}
  }
  {
    \end{tabular}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

---

Using the above by including as a package using the `\usepackage` command:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularDelimiter}

\begin{document}
\begin{mytabular}[@]{|c|c|}
A @ B\\
C @ D
\end{mytabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help by providing the details to do so.

Comment: You can just define it in the preamble. Or you could `\input` a very simple 'package' ...

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your requirement. If the requirement is just to avoid `\usepackage`, you could instead use `\RequirePackage` (same syntax).

You could also use `\input`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit

In case you must not include the environment in your preamble, the answer is unfortunately *no*.

If the environment is not built-in, i.e. it is not defined in `latex.ltx`, you have to either define it, or use a package which already define it. The first option is the original answer below, but as you can't do it, you only have one choice, that is to use `\usepackage`.

---

#### Original answer

Okay, I assume that you include the definition of `mytabular` environment in your package `tablularDelimiter`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment {mytabular} { O{\,} }
  {
    \char_set_catcode_other:N \&
    \char_set_catcode_alignment:n {`#1}
    \begin{tabular}
  }
  {
    \end{tabular}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{mytabular}[@]{|c|c|}
A @ B\\
C @ D
\end{mytabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, this is what I followed. But, the requirement says that the definition of the new environment needs to be in a separate .sty file and then use the same in another .tex file by including only the environment.

Comment: @Naman You should add that to the question. And the answer is no: you _must_ use a `\usepackage`, otherwise LaTeX doesn't know where to find the environment definition.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, and also, I regret for my incorrect question. Your answer really helped me this time!! :)

Comment: @Naman Glad to hear that. Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new environment in your preamble.

```
\newenvironment{name}[nargs]{begdef}{enddef}
```

where `name` is the name of the new environment as in `\begin{name}`... `\end{name}`. `nargs` is the number of arguments (0 to 9, but if 0 you can omit this), `begdef` is code to be executed at the beginning of the environment and `enddef` is code to be executed at the end of the environment.